# unable to open steps toolbox in Load runner

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I am using Loadrunner 12.53
when I tried to open Design>insert in script>New step 
Expected: I should be able to see the list of attributes

But under steps toolbox it is showing "There are no tools available for the cúrrent document!"

How can I enable steps toolbox?
I like to work using Design>insert in script>New step navigation as it is more 
easy to work than writing manually.

Thank you,

Comment: Which protocol are you using? This is the first time anyone complained about this, could you add a screenshot of the entire screen of VuGen when the problem happens?

Comment: Hello, It wasn't a problem!

Comment: I enabled my output tab when i tried to open desing >toolbox.

Comment: It is obvious that the attributes will not be seen, I reacted fast!        Thank you for the reply.